# Why Two Same-data SQLite Databases Have Different Sizes?

Tags: database, sqlite, csv, foxpro, dbf

I have some financial data for over 6600 stocks stored in a Foxpro database. I could download the database views into a set of 15 files, which I did first into .dbf files and then into .txt files (comma-delimited).

For the .dbf set of files I used a spatialite virtualization extension with Python and Sqlite to convert them into Sqlite tables then merged them into an 8-table database (Let's call it DBF-derived). So with c for cursor:

```
c.execute("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE temp_virt USING VirtualDbf({}, UTF-8)".format(file))
c.execute("CREATE TABLE {} AS SELECT * FROM temp_virt;".format(table_name))
```

For the .txt files, I used Pandas to convert and combine 12 of the 15 files into 5 CSV files, then I plied them with other remaining 3 .txt files in Python and Sqlite to create an 8-table database (let's call it CSV-derived) using a modified version of this code (from this [page](https://tentacles666.wordpress.com/tag/sqlite/)):

```
with open(csvfile, "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = True
    for row in reader:
        if header:
            # gather column names from the first row of the csv
            header = False

            sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s" % tablename
            c.execute(sql)
            sql = "CREATE TABLE %s (%s)" % (tablename,
                      ", ".join([ "%s text" % column for column in row ]))
            c.execute(sql)

            for column in row:
                if column.lower().endswith("_id"):
                    index = "%s__%s" % ( tablename, column )
                    sql = "CREATE INDEX %s on %s (%s)" % ( index, tablename, column )
                    c.execute(sql)

            insertsql = "INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s)" % (tablename,
                        ", ".join([ "?" for column in row ]))
```

- Now when I examined both sqlite databases, I found the following:

  - The DBF-derived database retained its ID column (although it was not designed as primary key).
  - The ID column did not survive the download to .txt in the CSV-derived db so I declared the stock ticker column as primary key.
  - The DBF-derived was not indexed in sqlite.
  - The CSV-derived got automatic indexing in sqlite.
  - Dates retained their date format in the CSV-derived db, whereas they turned into a number of days in the DBF-derived db.
  - The main data type that came through the vertualization process for the DBF-derived db was REAL, which I also set as the datatype as I
    created the CSV-derived db.
  - All else was identical, except that the CSV-derived db was 22% smaller in size than the DBF-derived, and I am puzzled as to why
    considering that it is indexed and has the same data and datatype.
    The two databases technically display the same information in the DB
    Browser program.

Any explanation as to why the difference in size? Is it because of the 3 .txt files that I did not convert to CSV?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand what you are doing and particularly why you would ever want to use a CSV in between when you could directly get data from another database system. Anyway, it is your choice, the difference is probably for the fact that VFP DBF data with character fields have trailing spaces. Say a 30 chars field, having a single letter in it still has a length of 30. Your conversion to SQLite might not be trimming the trailing spaces, while in a CSV file those data are already saved as trimmed. 
Probably the easiest and most reliable way would be to directly create the SQLite tables and fill them with data from within a VFP program (using VFP is not a must of course, could be done in any language).

Comment: Thank you Cetin. This is helpful to know but I cannot seem to find any trailing spaces on close examination of the DBF-sourced char fields in DP Browser. 
As for why go the CSV route, the program from which I download the data allows saving only in DBF or CSV. It does not have the facility to directly save in SQLite. So I have to use either format first before I convert the files to SQLite, and so far the CSV route seems more efficient.

Comment: IMHO data transfers using CSV is prone to errors. Whenever there is a chance, I would use database to database transfer. In your case DBF is a better choice IMHO.

Comment: Thank you again Cetin. Strangely, I have found that using DBF has produced inaccuracies. The DBF route returns dates as number of days (from a certain date) and some of those dates have strangely been replaced with NULL, whereas all the dates have fully survived the CSV transfer and are represented as MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: That means that you are doing something wrong. In database systems (most if not all) the date(time) is stored as numbers. But when you store, query etc the drivers are aware that it is a date. With CSV however you have to tell that you are getting a date in a specific format. Anyway if you are sure CSV is good then use it.